# Maintaining order using Amazon's Kinesis with atleast 1000 messages per sec

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, aws-sdk-nodejs, amazon-kcl

I am trying to send 1000's of messages in sequence using Amazon's Kinesis but messages being received by kinesis consumer is not in sequence.
Things I have tried :

1. Used `putRecord()` method to send with *SequenceNumberForOrdering*. 
   Achieved ordered sequence with this but throughput is very less.
2. Used `putRecords` method to send but not successful.
3. Used KCL + Amazon's API consumer.

Answer (score 1):

Kinesis maintains sequence within shards, not across all shards in a stream. I am guessing you have more than 1 shard in your stream and hence observing the read records out of sequence. (You can also quickly validate this by repeating #2 with just 1 shard in your stream.)

Quote from [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=677513):

> please note that Record Sequence Numbers (RSNs) are not globally tracked in the stream and are instead only tracked per shard.

Comment: Yes it maintains sequence within shards only. But if you are sending many messages at once, it is not maintaining the order. Because of latency issues. Kinesis is only maintaining the order of messages within KinesisQueue but not how producer is sending them.

Comment: what is KinesisQueue?